# AS3: Why is a line created with .graphics appearing in two different places and when removed with parent.visible = false, only one goes?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Nobody seems to have this question already so I asked it because I've spent a few hours trying to debug this and can't find a solution;

Essentially, I have a function called `draw`, which is declared in my document class:

```
public function draw(Target: MovieClip,mX: int,mY: int,lX: int,lY: int):void {
    Target.graphics.clear();
    Target.graphics.lineStyle(1,0x000000,1);
    Target.graphics.moveTo(mX,mY);
    Target.graphics.lineTo(lX,lY);  
}
```

I call it later to draw two lines, on two different MovieClips:

```
draw(Line,Line.mX,Line.mY,Mirror.x + (Mirror.width / 2),Line.lY);
draw(nextLine,(Mirror.x + (Mirror.width / 2)),200,(Mirror.x + (Mirror.width / 2)),0);
```

where

```
var Line: MovieClip = new MovieClip();
var Mirror: MovieClip = new mirror();
```

and `Mirror` is draggable, so `Mirror.x` changes whenever it is dragged.

`Line` is a line made using `.graphics` and Line.mX is equal to the `Line.graphics.moveTo` X value last time it was modified. `Line.mY` is the same, but for the Y coordinate. I set these values by doing this:

```
Line.mX = 0;
Line.mY = 200;
Line.lX = 550; 
Line.lY = 200;
```

But with whatever values I want to draw the line, with `lX` and `lY` being equal to the X and Y coordinates of `Line.graphics.lineTo`. Then I draw `Line` using my `draw` function like this:

```
draw(Line,Line.mX,Line.mY,Line.lX,Line.lY);
```

Then it gets more complex because, actually, `Line` is just one line in an array of lines, created like this:

```
public var lines = [line0,line1,line2,line3,line4,line5,line6,line7,line8];
```

and each of those lines is created like this (with 0 being replaced by the line's number, respectively):

```
public var line0: MovieClip = new MovieClip();
```

then I give each line a number and a name, add them to the stage and hide them like this:

```
for each(var setupLine:MovieClip in lines) {
    setupLine.num = (lines.indexOf(setupLine));
    setupLine.name = ('line' + setupLine.num);

    addChild(setupLine);
    setupLine.visible = false;
}
```

Then, after making `line0` visible, because I need to see it at the start, I loop through each line in a function that runs on `ENTER_FRAME`, and set the value of `nextLine` to a different value each time I run the loop like this:

```
for each(var Line:MovieClip in lines) {
    nextLine = this['line' + (Line.num + 1)];
}
```

Within that loop, I then loop through a few other arrays, then check for a collision with the selected `Line` and another selected MovieClip from another array, which I wont go into or this question will be longer than the code for node.js.

So essentially, if the collision with the two MovieClips is present, I draw the line that I mentioned at the top of my question. But for some reason, although `Line` draws correctly, `nextLine` draws correctly, but a duplicate of it is drawn across the Y axis at 0, and stops where `nextLine` is on the Y axis (`nextLine` is vertical, so it has the same Y value at the start as at the end).

Even stranger, when I try to hide `nextLine` if the collision with the two MovieClips is no longer present, using this code:

```
nextLine.visible = false;
```

it only hides the version of `nextLine` that runs along the top of the stage, which I didn't even intend to create in the start.

---

**EDIT**

---

[here is a link to the current source code](http://pastebin.com/a5skQkwv)
[Here is a link to the entire project files with the original source code](http://raphaelhennessy.com/LightStage/LightStage.zip) 
copy/paste the new source code from the pastebin link to get the new version

---

Thanks in advance,

-Raph

Comment: Update your question with all the contextual code, eg where you're doing your collisions, your enter frame handler, etc.

Comment: @LDMS A bit confused about what you mean, but I added the source code because that's what I think you mean.

Comment: While all isn't necessary, it is helpful. That said that's a lot of superfluous code to sift through.  Some tips,  in AS3/Java/JS , standard practice is to make Class names start with a capital letter, and instances start with lowercase (you'll notice how Stackoverflow has code highlighting that assumes this practice) - makes everything more readable. (this is for future reference)

Comment: You may want to explore the idea of using custom classes.  really your program should have a `Globe` class where inside that class you can encapsulate all the globe functionality/Properties.  Same with the line and mirrors

Comment: @LDMS about custom classes, I will incorporate them into my code, but I dont see how they will fix this problem right at the moment

Comment: They won't per se, but they sure make it easier to figure it out!   Can you explain what's happening in your enter frame handler more?  Or rather explain what you want to be happening.    I'm not sure what the relationship is between Globe's and selected timer and Mirrors.  I'm having a hard time grasping what the game actually does.

Comment: @LDMS i uploaded the project files to http://raphaelhennessy.com/misc/LightStage/LightStage,zip

Comment: That is an amazing idea.  A small description about the what the game is would be helpful as well though.

Comment: Without knowing what is supposed to be happening in the game, I can't really help.  Though if you want I can send you back some structure/efficiency recommendations.    Is the idea that a line is suppose to reflect off the mirror/paddle and the goal is strike the globe with the vertical line?    Here is a cleaner refactoring: http://pastebin.com/nQGjzPBU

Comment: @LDMS what you did is amazing - sorry I forgot to mention what I'm trying to accomplish in the end - I'm not sure how but you seem to have figured it out pretty well - the player has to position the mirror so that it bounces the light that enters the stage up into the globe. 
Only problem is that I'm getting an error:

`5006: An ActionScript file can not have more than one externally visible definition: LightStage, Mirror`
I tried combining the code into a single package with seperate classes and I got the same error, just referencing LightStage.LightStage and LightStage.Mirror instead

Comment: @LDMS I spent a while working with your code and made it run without errors. Included the code on pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/a5skQkwv)

Comment: @LDMS ok I have figured out how to fix the problem using your code. Post an answer and in it tell me how to make all the movieclips in the globes and mirrors vector arrays be instances of the 'globe' and 'mirror' AS3 linkage MovieClip in my library and I'll mark it as correct

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that All the packages in the pastebin code should be their own .as file (named the same as the class) - but putting them outside the package in the same .as does work too (as long as you the only place you ever need to reference them is inside that one package)

Comment: Since I still don't know what the issue is/was, it would be best if you answered your own question I think.    One other step you may have already done, is when you split out all your classes to their own .as file, you can then Link your display asset in FlashPro to that class.  So in your linkage settings for globe and mirror, link them to `Mirror` and `Globe` class.   This won't work though unless you move each package to it's own .as file.  So you should have a `Mirror.as` and a `Globe.as` and a `Line.as`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out how to do this, code is

```
package {

    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.utils.*;
    import flash.display.*;

    [SWF(backgroundColor="0xbdc3c7")]
    public class LightStage extends MovieClip {

        //import classes
        public var globeClass:Globe = new Globe();
        public var mirrorClass:Mirror = new Mirror();
        public var lineClass:Line = new Line();

        //create all stage objects
        public var curLine:Line
        public var nextLine:Line;

        public var curMirror:Mirror;

        //create containers
        public var mirrors:Vector.<Mirror> = new Vector.<Mirror>(); //a vector is an array, but every member has to be (or subclass) the specified class
        public var globes:Vector.<Globe> = new Vector.<Globe>();
        public var lines:Vector.<Line> = new Vector.<Line>();

        trace('lightstage: working');
        //create level object
        public var curLevel:int = -1;

        //create dependent variables
        public var kill: Boolean = true;

        //init function
        public function LightStage() {
            //setup MovieClips

            var i:int = 0;

            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                mirrors.push(new Mirror());
            }

            for (i = 0; i < 4;i++ ) {
                globes.push(new Globe());
            }

            var tmpLine:Line;
            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                tmpLine = new Line();
                lines.push(tmpLine);

                addChild(tmpLine);
                tmpLine.visible = false;
            }

            //create ENTER_FRAME listener
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,enterFrame);

            //start the game
            levelUp();
        }


        //levelUp function
        public function levelUp() {
            curLevel++;

            curLine = lines[curLevel]; //set line to the current level 

            curLine.curX = 0; 
            curLine.curY = 200;
            curLine.draw(550, 200);

            curLine.visible = true;

            //show and position mirrors and globes
            curMirror = mirrors[curLevel];
            addChild(curMirror);
            curMirror.x = 250;
            curMirror.y = 350;

            var curGlobe:Globe = globes[curLevel];
            addChild(curGlobe);
            curGlobe.x = 100;
            curGlobe.y = 50;

            //set mirror types
            curMirror.gotoAndStop(2);

            trace("you are now on level " + (curLevel + 1) + "!");

        }

        //ENTER_FRAME function
        public function enterFrame(event:Event) {
            //line1.visible = true;

            for (var i:int = 0; i < lines.length;i++){
                if (i < lines.length - 1) nextLine = lines[i + 1]; //check for out of bounds before assignment next line

                if (lines[i].visible == true) {
                    kill = true;
                    for each(var mirror:Mirror in mirrors) {
                        if (lines[i].visible && mirror.stage && mirror.hitTestObject(lines[i])) {  //for efficiency, do the hit test last in the if statement
                            for each(var globe:Globe in globes) {
                                //Looped through Mirrors and Lines and checked for collision - if collision is present, we loop through globes here

                                if (nextLine && nextLine.stage) {
                                    addChild(nextLine);
                                }

                                //check for active globes
                                if (lines[i].visible && lines[i].hitTestObject(globe)) {
                                    //check if the selected line touches the selected globe - if it does then we will start the timer for that globe
                                    if (!globe.running){
                                        globe.start();
                                        //trace('timing');
                                        kill = false;
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    globe.reset();
                                }

                                switch(mirror.currentFrame) {
                                    case 1:
                                        break;

                                    case 2:
                                        //trace('live a life you will remember' + Math.random());
                                        if(nextLine) nextLine.visible = true;
                                        lines[i].draw(mirror.x + (mirror.width / 2),lines[i].curY);
                                        if (nextLine) {
                                            nextLine.curX = mirror.x + (mirror.width / 2);
                                            nextLine.curY = 200;
                                            nextLine.draw(mirror.x + (mirror.width / 2), 0);
                                        }
                                        kill = false;
                                        break;
                                    case 3:
                                    case 4:
                                    case 5:
                                    case 6:
                                    case 7:
                                    case 8:
                                    case 9:
                                    case 10:
                                    case 11:
                                    case 12:
                                        trace(mirror.currentFrame);
                                        kill = false;
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else if (lines[i].visible && mirror.stage && lines[i].stage){
                            if (kill && nextLine){
                                nextLine.graphics.clear();
                                nextLine.visible = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

//MIRROR CLASS DECLARATION
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
class Mirror extends MovieClip {
    trace('mirror: working');
    public function Mirror() {
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,onDown,false,0,true);
    }

    private function onDown(e:MouseEvent):void {
        //add the mouse up listener on the stage, that way it's consistent even if the user drags so fast that the mouse leaves the bounds of the mirror
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onUp, false, 0, true);
        this.startDrag();
    }

    private function onUp(e:MouseEvent):void {
        //we need to remove the listener from the stage now
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onUp, false);

        this.stopDrag();
    }
}

//LINE CLASS DECLARATION
import flash.display.Graphics;
class Line extends MovieClip {
    trace('line: working');
    public var curX:int;
    public var curY:int;

    public function Line():void {

    }

    public function draw(toX:int,toY:int):void {
        graphics.clear();
        graphics.lineStyle(1,0x000000,1);
        graphics.moveTo(curX,curY);
        graphics.lineTo(toX, toY);

        curX = toX;
        curY = toY;
    }
}

//GLOBE CLASS DECLARATION
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
class Globe extends MovieClip {
    trace('globe: working');
    private var timer:Timer = new Timer(3 * 100, 5);

    public function Globe():void {
        timer = new Timer(300, 5);
        timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, repeatShine, false, 0, true);
    }

    public function reset():void {
        timer.reset();
    }

    public function start():void {
        timer.start();
    }

    public function get running():Boolean { return timer.running; };

    private function repeatShine(e:TimerEvent):void {

    }
}
```